# how to write HTML tags with jQuery n json dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I need to write html code into the following div with jquery

```
<div id="addme"></div>
```

following is my html with php

```
<div class="col-md-4 product secondproduct">
    <div class="images1">
        <a
            href=" <?php echo base_url();?>products/details/<?php echo $product->productid?>">
            <img
            src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/products/<?php echo $product->productimage;?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="title1">
            <?php echo $product->productname;?>
    </div>
    <div class="price1">
            Rs. <?php echo $product->productprice;?>
    </div>

    <div class="productadd">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/productadd">
            <div class="qtyout">
                QTY : <input type="text" class="qty" name="qty" value="1" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number"
                value="<?php echo $product->productid;?>" /> <input
                type="hidden" name="price"
                value="<?php echo $product->productprice;?>" /> <input type="hidden"
                name="title" value="<?php echo $product->productname;?>" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Add To Cart</button>

        </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

actually i want to populate these html & php with json & query. And kinda getting lots of error. main problem is, i don't know how to write these about of html tags inside jquery and loop through json data.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Something like following:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON({"productid":"2","categoryid":"1","manufacturerid":"2","name":"Abraham Lincoln Printed T-Shirt","price":"1250.00","color":"red","description":"Print Name: Abraham Lincoln\r\n100% Cotton\r\nMade in Nepal\r\nRegular fit\r\nHalf sleeve","quantity":"20","otherdetails":"Available in all sizes.","isadvertised":"1","isnew":"1","image":"hazy-crazy-t-shirt.jpg","manuid"‌​:"2"}');

$(".image1").html(obj.image);
$(".color1").html(obj.color);
```

Comment: It say **undefined**   there is [{"a":"b"}] its is something problem with javascript array or object i think.

Comment: it need something like `$('.image1').html(obj[1].image)` Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

to add something in the addme div you do

```
$("#addme").html('insert content here');
```

or you can append something(keeps whats there and add stuff to the end):

```
$("#addme").append('insert content here');
```

for the json. Once you have a json string you do

```
var yourdata = JSON.parse(jsonstring)
```

Hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data in json by ajax than you can simply append in html with the specific div, follow the code below:

```
Using ajax return :
var myAjaxreturn = "Your code which is to append";

<div id='addme'></div>

$('#addme').html(myAjaxreturn);
```

Comment: Ajax response is in following format, so it don't do any better with $().html() `[{"productid":"2","categoryid":"1","manufacturerid":"2","name":"Abraham Lincoln Printed T-Shirt","price":"1250.00","color":"red","description":"Print Name: Abraham Lincoln\r\n100% Cotton\r\nMade in Nepal\r\nRegular fit\r\nHalf sleeve","quantity":"20","otherdetails":"Available in all sizes.","isadvertised":"1","isnew":"1","image":"hazy-crazy-t-shirt.jpg","manuid":"2"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery append() inserts content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
var response = "your ajax response";

$( "#addme" ).append( response );
```

**OR**

```
$( "#addme" ).html( response );
```

Hope this helps. not tested